Fast hashing of integer sequences in nympy/torch ? (except dot product with random vector - it is quite good, but may be something else?)
Consider sequences of integers like (1,0,2,4,...,100).
We have many(!) of them, and we need to hash them and it should be very fast in Python - so I am seeking methods using numpy/torch - i.e. without  slow Python loops.
The simple and efficient method which works - is to generate random integer vector -
and just consider the dot products - which can be implemented in just one matrix product:
np.matmul(array_of_sequences, random_int_vector )

Question 1: any ideas to do better ?
Any comments/ideas/suggestions are welcome !
C++ people suggested me something like that: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/466399#2600835 but not sure it is Python relevant .
One of the troubles with the method above - it cannot work on old GPU like P100, which does not support multiplication of integer matrices. And when integers are converted to floats,
we have another trouble: float multiplication may lose precision and hashing will not work correctly. When hash is float - it is more to explain why: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/468370 . But for integer hashes there is also problem, that is more surprising.

This can't be answered as is, because the requirements are not specific. There are arbitrarily many reasons why someone might want to compute a hash, and each would make different factors more or less important.

@KarlKnechtel E.g. Faster, but with the same probability of the collision.  I welcome any ideas.

The "probability of collision" will depend on how you use the hash values, as well as statistical properties of the input which we can't even begin to guess. And depending on those things, one or another algorithm could have better or worse performance in that regard. There are applications where a "hash function" that takes the object's memory address, or even just returns a constant, would be adequate. There are others where that would obviously be terrible.

Use case: sequences are permutations of the (0,1,2,3...n) i.e. all permuation have the same probability. That fixes the statistical properties.

The fastest hash function is simply to return the input (so not a hash). Sometimes, it works fine and is the optimal approach (especially for small numbers in hash tables). Then, the question why you need to hash numbers in the first place. There is no hash which is fast and great in all cases, generic hash function are always clearly sub-optimal. This is why KarlKnechtel ask for more details.

Besides, you should not put links referring to post extending the question on StackOverflow : the question should be self-content (to help future reader since most links are often dead several years later).

Example of (rather expensive) generic hash function are sha1, sh256 and md5. The 2 first are known to be very-well balanced. The second is secure while the later is not. Most fast hash function should never be use for sake of security (does it matter for you?). Faster ones are crc32/crc64 which are still rather robust but still rather expensive. Adler should be a bit faster but AFAIK it is outdated. Fastest relatively-good non-cryptographic generic ones are the one multiplying the integer with a big prime and then using a modulus. Others use shift but are often bad hash (though fast ones)

Guys, I know general bla-bla-bla , my PhD was 25 years ago. If you have something reasonable to share - please share your knowledge, except that "many pathatological situatuations can happen" (but never happens in practice). It is not about theory - it is about practice.

If someone needs something more concrete - let me repeat - vectors are permutations of (0,1,2,3...) with equal probability. Challnege - hash faster than mentioned in the post - with the same probability of collision. Hash should be integer number. But I welcome any kind of useful information around the question.

I give you a list of (8) practical hash functions from the slowest to the fastest. Did you actually tried them? (especially the FMA-based one for GPUs). Is so, what is wrong with them? By the way, you can pack 32-bit int to 16-bit ones if n<65536.

If you write any code in the answer form I will upvote it. But just out of curiosity - do you understand how fast np.matmul is working ? And how many out of yours 8 methods would be comparable ?

How large can n be?

@WarrenWeckesser my first concern is around 50 or like that. If the projects goes well, in some future it can grow to 1000-10_000, but that is quite far from now. Any way any information is welcome.
The number of vectors which I want to hash is say 10_000_000

"I am seeking methods using numpy/torch" I do not think Numpy can be very good in this case. IDK for torch. Is this fine for you to use other libraries? (I am thinking about Numba for example).  --  "do you understand how fast np.matmul is working" Yes, very well. I wrote faster alternatives for specific use-cases several times (and I also massively optimized many core functions of Numpy btw ;) ).

@JérômeRichard The question is  DELIBRATELY made open-ended, so any people who have any relevant experience can share their knowledge. So have something to write - write.  One can write in format "If the use case is ... , then the method ... is good".  I am 99% sure that in the particular setup which I described: hashing integer sequence more or less uniformly distrbuted within -L,L , with number << 2^64 , the numpy way is the best - I see zero collisions - checked up to about  1_000_000_000 vectors to hash, and speed is very fast. But again - the question welcomes any information.

This answer provide faster alternatives to np.matmul while using the same approach.
Here is the initial setup used to benchmark the code:
import numpy as np  # Version: 1.24.3

# Note: 
# Items of random_int_vector and array_of_sequences are 32-bit integers
# It might be 64-bit on some machine (eg. on Linux) so a manual conversion is needed
n = 50
seq_count = 10_000_000
random_int_vector = np.random.randint(0, 1000, n)
array_of_sequences = np.array([np.random.permutation(n) for i in range(seq_count)])

First of all, np.matmul is clearly not optimal in integer-based arrays. Indeed, Numpy calls the highly optimized BLAS primitive for floating-point arrays but it uses its own sub-optimal implementation for integer-based array so far. This implementation is sequential (like all Numpy internal functions not to be confused with BLAS ones). A faster implementation consists calling np.einsum instead which is usually a bit faster (but still sequential on my machine). Here is an example:
# 532 ms ± 564 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.matmul(array_of_sequences, random_int_vector)

# 228 ms ± 504 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
np.einsum('ij,j', array_of_sequences, random_int_vector)

While np.einsum is better, it is still sub-optimal and use 1 thread. We can speed up the computation using a more efficient compiled code and multiple thread thanks to Numba. Here is the resulting code:
import numba as nb  # Version: 0.58.1

@nb.njit('(int32[:,::1],int32[::1])', parallel=True)
def faster_int_matmul(array_of_sequences, random_int_vector):
    seq_count, n = array_of_sequences.shape
    out = np.empty(seq_count, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in nb.prange(seq_count):
        s = 0
        for j in range(n):
            s += array_of_sequences[i, j] * random_int_vector[j]
        out[i] = s
    return out

# Sequential: 127 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# Parallel: 58.1 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
faster_int_matmul(array_of_sequences, random_int_vector)

This solution is nearly-optimal for 32-bit integer-based arrays on my machine. Indeed, the time to read array_of_sequences and store the output on a 40 GiB/s RAM like mine is at least 48.4 ms (optimal time on my CPU). In practice, mixed read/stores often causes the CPU to hardly saturate the RAM and overheads like page-faults also prevent the RAM to be fully saturated. In the end, this Numba implementation saturates 83% of my RAM. Put it shortly, it is memory-bound. This explains why the parallel implementation is only 2.2 times faster on my 6-core CPU (i5-9600KF).
The only solution to make that significantly faster is to operate on smaller integers like 16-bit integers. That being said, number should fit in 16-bit integers. Moreover, in practice, Numba generates a significantly less efficient code in this case (taking 93.3 ms) so it does not worth it. This seems to be due to a missed/inefficient use of SIMD instructions. While a lower-level C implementation can certainly fix this issue, one should keep in mind that the speed up will not be higher than x2 (since 16-bit integers are twice smaller and the operation was memory-bound on 32-bit ones).
The provided implementation should be efficient for significantly bigger n as long as random_int_vector fits in the L1/L2 cache. This means it should be fast for n < 10_000 (at least on on all mainstream CPUs).

Thanks ! What about the data types returned by these methods ? is it np.int64 as desired, (otherwise collision probability increases) ? Is it controlled that there is no floating operations on intermediate steps ? (Otherwise floating point is BAD for hashing since it is NOT deterministic - depends on RAM positions - see e.g. https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/468370 )

AFAIK Numba use 64-bit integer by default so s is of type int64. That being said, the output is explicitly defined as a np.int32 array. You can replace dtype=np.int32 with np.int64 if needed and replace s = 0 by s = np.int64(0) to be safe. You can even use unsigned integers to be safer (like np.uint64). It may impact performance but I expect the computation to be still rather memory-bound (dependent of the target machine). Collision should indeed be more frequent on 32-bit integers but the best is to test it.

Thanks . In my cases n = 50 and I am using uint8 for array and int64 for hash-vector. Can it be supported in your approaches ?

There is no floating-point operation here. Note that it is often better to be safe to specify the type of the variable since Numba can unify types and some unified types can results in floating-point types (sad)... AFAIK it can happen when you mix 64-bit signed integers with non-signed ones so I advise you to use only unsigned ones here. Btw, note FP is deterministic but not associative (doing this wrong assumption in parallel codes is what causes non-deterministic results).

By the way some colleagues suggested me an alogorithmic solution trick - just choose only a part of positions of "vector-array" and hash only it. It should work for random permutations

Yes. I think you just need to replace the current signature with (int8[:,::1],int64[::1]). Be aware that 8-bit integer are limited to the range [-128;127[. Unsigned 8-bit integer are in the range [0;255[.

This can significantly increase the probability of collisions though the probability of two random permutation to be equal is very small with n=50. It may be fine, even with millions of permutations. That being said, CPUs read items in memory with a granularity of 64 bytes, that is 64 8-bit integers. Thus, it should not speed up the computation with n=50. It might be a good idea with large n value like >256 (since not all cache lines will be read from RAM).

Thanks ! The application is here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/growth-2-permutations-with-numpy?scriptVersionId=184047556&cellId=21 comments are welcome . The hash is used for fast check - graph node was visited before or not

By the way what about GPU - which do not support int matirces like P100 ?
And more generally - are there any ways to hash in that situations ? What about yours '8 methods" ? )

On GPU, you can do the same thing with a CUDA/OpenCL kernel. Maybe torch can do that but I do know this module. You just need to store the random_int_vector on LDS/shared-memory so to get better performance, but be aware that its space is very limited so for large n (e.g. >1000 ?) GPUs might be less efficient (than n ~= 128). For small n (<64), they will likely be sub-optimal since warp/wavefront are of size 32 and at least 64 active thread is often needed per block. Besides, loop unrolling may help a bit so to better use available registers.

Anyway, I expect the GPU implementation to quickly saturate the VRAM (like on CPU with the RAM) even with sub-optimal kernels. GPU generally have a much bigger memory throughput but data transfer to/from the CPU are very slow. So much that if you do not have the array stored on the GPU already, then using a GPU here is completely useless (the PCI bus and Nvlink are slower than the CPU RAM which is the bottleneck). If the input array is already on the GPU, then you may get a ~5x speed up (for a GPU at the same price than a CPU).

Regarding the "8 methods", the two last can certainly be equally fast than a matrix vector product (and quite similar actually). They cannot be faster since the operation is limited by the time to read the input and store the output. So if a matrix-vector product is fine to you, then keep it. The other mentioned methods should be more expensive though they may generate better hashes (less collisions). Hard to know how much without testing them.

Thank  you, merci beaucoup

My colleagues ask: about jit part - if we rewrite it in C/C++ - would be faster ?

It will not be faster in C/C++ or any other language as long as RAM is the bottleneck on the target machine.

Also please note Numba should be close to speed of C/C++ here since 1. the function is compiled ahead of time during its definition (thanks to its explicit signature), 2. Numba uses the same LLVM backend than Clang in C/C++, 3. Numba overheads (eg. bound checking) are negligible here. There is an exception : C/C++ can provide missing low-level features. Indeed, if the code is not memory bound on the target machine, then C/C++ SIMD intrinsics might help to improve speed for 16-bit / 8-bit inputs.

If you have some time please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78896180/625396
