What are the fastest ways to check interesection between two pytorch vectors?
Question: Consider two pytorch vectors v1,v2 - what are the fastest ways to deterimine do they have any common element ?  Suggestions/ideas/experience welcome !
Setup: data types: torch.int64,  lengths v1 - 10^6-10^8, v2 - 10^5-10^7, v1 is precomputed (only unique elements, sorted), v2 is changing each time. Typical situation - NO COMMON elements.
Very preferably working for both CPU and GPU.
What I have considered:

torch.isin(v1,v2 , assume_unique = True)  - pay attention that assume_unique = True - speed-ups up to 10 times !

torch.searchsorted(v1sorted,v2); followed by (v1s[ts] == v2).sum().item() .
That is fastest option in many cases. But SURPRISE - searchsorted is much faster than (v1s[ts] == v2).sum().item() . So seemningly much more simple operation consumes more time, may be there is some way to speedup ?

Some other ways - but they are slower





Method
Time
Device
L1
L2
Intersection size
L1 unique
L2 unique




isin direct
1.365
cpu
1,000,000
1,000,000
0
1,000,000
1,000,000


isin assume_unique
0.778
cpu
1,000,000
1,000,000
0
1,000,000
1,000,000


search sorted
0.136
cpu
1,000,000
1,000,000
0
1,000,000
1,000,000


isin direct
13.286
cpu
10,000,000
1,000,000
0
10,000,000
1,000,000


isin assume_unique
1.823
cpu
10,000,000
1,000,000
0
10,000,000
1,000,000


search sorted
0.321
cpu
10,000,000
1,000,000
0
10,000,000
1,000,000



For GPU
(there is bug in torch randint - so sizes of intersections - are not as expected, but timing seems to be correct):
Bug in torch randint : https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/125224
pull request
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/126066



Method
Time
Device
L1
L2
Intersection size
L1 unique
L2 unique




isin direct
0.005
cuda
1,000,000
1,000,000
311,872
1,000,000
1,000,000


isin assume_unique
0.003
cuda
1,000,000
1,000,000
311,872
1,000,000
1,000,000


search sorted
0.001
cuda
1,000,000
1,000,000
311,872
1,000,000
1,000,000


isin direct
0.034
cuda
10,000,000
1,000,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
1,000,000


isin assume_unique
0.011
cuda
10,000,000
1,000,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
1,000,000


search sorted
0.003
cuda
10,000,000
1,000,000
99,480
10,000,000
1,000,000


isin direct
0.296
cuda
100 000 000
1 000 000
1023183.0
98845253.0
999877.0


isin assume_unique
0.081
cuda
100 000 000
1 000 000
999877.0
98845253.0
999877.0


search sorted
0.003
cuda
100 000 000
1 000 000
10019.0
98845253.0
999877.0



Suprise - for BOTH vectors of same size like 10** 7, or similar both vectors - all methods gives approximately the same



Method
Time
Device
L1
L2
Intersection size
L1 unique
L2 unique




isin direct
0.041
cuda
10 000 000
10 000 000
4965335
9988353
9988316


isin direct v2 v1
0.034
cuda
10 000 000
10 000 000
4965266
9988353
9988316


isin assume_unique
0.020
cuda
10 000 000
10 000 000
4956632
9988353
9988316


isin assume_unique v2 v1
0.020
cuda
10 000 000
10 000 000
4956632
9988353
9988316


search sorted
0.026
cuda
10 000 000
10 000 000
4965266
9988353
9988316






Method
Time
Device
L1
L2
Intersection size
L1 unique
L2 unique




isin direct
0.354
cuda
100 000 000
50 000 000
50574973
98845711
49711185


isin direct v2 v1
0.229
cuda
100 000 000
50 000 000
49996126
98845711
49711185


isin assume_unique
0.138
cuda
100 000 000
50 000 000
49707311
98845711
49711185


isin assume_unique v2 v1
0.137
cuda
100 000 000
50 000 000
49707311
98845711
49711185


search sorted
0.184
cuda
100 000 000
50 000 000
49996126
98845711
49711185



Experiments are here:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/speed-tests-isin-searchsorted-etc
Codelets:
Way 1:
m = torch.isin(v1,v2)
s = m.sum().item()

Way 2:
v2unique = torch.unique(v2)
m = torch.isin(v1unique,v2unique, assume_unique = True)
s = m.sum().item()

Way 3:
ts = torch.searchsorted(v1s,v2)
ts[ts>=len(v1)] = len(v1)-1 
s = (v1s[ts] == v2).sum().item()

PS
Related: Finding non-intersection of two pytorch tensors

See The most efficient way rather than using np.setdiff1d and np.in1d, to remove common values of 1D arrays with unique values on CPU. It should be especially well suited for no common elements.

This one may also be useful on CPU: What is the fastest way to find intersection of two NumPy arrays while preserving order? . Whether the order should be preserved or not matters a lot (especially on GPUs).

For your use case, are you trying to find the common items, or are you simply looking for a true/false result if an intersection does/doesn't exist?

@karl primary it  is just true False check. Typically it will be false.

@JérômeRichard Thanks for sharing !
